# Generic class with generic type parameter stored in string

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there a way in C# to get the definition of a type from a string? I'd like to use it as a generic type parameter.

This is what i'd like to achieve in the end.

```
    string classname = "Class1";
    GenericClass<Class1> gc = new GenericClass<Class1>();
    gc.Method();
```

is there any possible way?

Comment: You mean creating a type on the fly?

Comment: You can create the instance, but from that point onward you will be forced to work with it using reflection (unless there is additional information you have not given) -- i.e. you cannot then write `gc.Method()`. This will be slow and the compiler will not be able to catch any errors you make. Are you sure that's what you need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use reflection to do it and sometimes it cannot be too safe, try something like this [article sample](http://omegacoder.com/?p=38).

```
Type d1 = typeof(GenericClass<>);

Type[] typeArgs = { Type.GetType("Class1") };

Type makeme = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

object o = Activator.CreateInstance(makeme);
```

But you will not get all intellisense from visual studio.